# subsonic 3.0.0.3 with mysql can not work in .net 4.0?

Tags: mysql, subsonic3

i have installed vs2010 beta2, create a MVC website, i want to use subsoinc access a mysql database in **SimpleRepository**, when run the website, i get error: "**Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.** ".

```
var repo = new SimpleRepository("NorthwindMySql", SimpleRepositoryOptions.None);
var user = repo.Find<Models.User>(u => u.Username == "mm");

ViewData["UserData"] = user;
```

then, i use my vs2008 do the same thing, this time, the website works just fine.
how can i fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you need to add this to your web.config file:

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

as the MySQL driver didn't register with the .NET 4 machine.config (.NET 4 was installed only after the MySQL connectivity drivers were installed).

Notice that the version of the MySQL driver you have may vary.