# Error:"Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed."

Tags: asp.net

i having an error said that "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed."

I'm using (visual studio 2010) with (Sqlserver 2008 R2) And (.net framework 4.0)
(ASP.net:C#)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use SubSonic for vb.net windows apps and mySql and had the same error as you, 
I've just installed vb.net 2010 express

I read a stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062189/subsonic-3-0-0-3-with-mysql-can-not-work-in-net-4-0/4704797#4704797) which suggested that the db connector had been installed before .net v4 (vs2010) hence they couldn't be found, I thought this sounded feasible so I downloaded the latest MySql connector, uninstalled the old one and installed the new one. The next time I ran my project the simpleRepository worked straight away!

I was blaming SubSonic! but it really is great!

Hope this might help